# Disable item selection on WinUI3 listview

Tags: c#, winui-3

In my WinUI3 app I have a ListView control that illustrates the 'current' item in another part of the app. For visual consistency this is done by binding to the `SelectedItem` property of the ListView. I would like to stop the user from being able to select other items in the ListView, for example by clicking them.

What I've tried so far:

1. Setting `IsItemClickEnabled="False"` on the ListView. No apparent effect.
2. Setting `SelectionMode="None"` on the ListView. Disables the display of the current item.
3. Placing a transparent control in front of the ListView. Stops scrolling of the ListView.
4. Editing the visual state of ListViewItem as per visc's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515455/listview-disabling-item-click/47425613#47425613). Disables the display of the current item.
5. Setting `IsHitTestVisible = false` on the item containers (as per mm8's answer below). Stops all interaction on the child controls e.g. scrolling of the child ListViews in the example code below.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Edit: The challenge seems to be blocking user selection without blocking all interaction. My ListView actually contains other listviews, like the code below. Crucially, I'd like to retain the ability for the user to (horizontally) scroll the child ListView items.

XAML:

```xml
       <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
            <TextBox x:Name="SelectedItemTextBox" Grid.Row="0" />
            <ListView
                Grid.Row="1"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectedIndex="2"> 

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Margin="0,8,0,0"
                                Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            <ListView
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Margin="4,0,0,4"
                                ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubItems}"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                SelectedIndex="2">

                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                            </ListView>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

C#:

```cs
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Initially set the target outside the dialog
            RootCanvas.Children.Add(TeachingTip);
            TeachingTip.Target = DialogButton;
            TeachingTip.IsOpen = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                MyItem item = new() { Name = i.ToString() };
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    item.SubItems.Add($"Sub item {j + 1}");
                }
                Items.Add(item);
            }            
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items { get; } = new();
    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public List<string> SubItems { get; } = new();
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You're essentially trying to prevent a control from doing what it is designed to do. Wouldn't it make more sense to use a different control? Perhaps the ItemsRepeater is more suitable for your needs.

Comment: @EddieLotter That is an option, but as I'm aiming for visual consistency with other ListViews I'd hoped disabling one piece of functionality would be simpler then replicating a whole bunch of other aspects

Comment: Perhaps you just need [Scroll viewer controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/scroll-controls). It's unnecessary to violate `ListView` and in the meanwhile cooperate with it.

Comment: *The challenge seems to be blocking clicks, without blocking all interaction.* Have you considered [the space bar or taps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/listview-and-gridview#single-selection)?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I phrased that badly-edited to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make each `ListViewItem` un-clickable. The key point is to apply the `DefaultListViewItemStyle` so you won't drop the default property settings and default `VisualStates`.

This is the code of the sample app I created to check this answer. This works including the scrolling.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="ListViewExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:ListViewExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <TextBox
            x:Name="SelectedItemTextBox"
            Grid.Row="0" />
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedItemTextBox.Text, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}"
                    TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ListViewExample;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Items.Add($"{i + 1}");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of using `ListView`, you can create a custom `ItemsControl` and use `ListViewItem` for each item so you can have the *Selected* look:

**CustomItemsControl.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ListViewExSampleApp;

public class CustomItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(SelectedIndex),
            typeof(int),
            typeof(CustomItemsControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(-1, OnSelectedIndexPropertyChanged));

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value);
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        ListViewItem container = new();

        container.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (sender is ListViewItem listViewItem &&
                listViewItem.DataContext is object item &&
                Items.IndexOf(item) == this.SelectedIndex)
            {
                listViewItem.IsSelected = true;
            }
        };

        return container;
    }

    private static void OnSelectedIndexPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is CustomItemsControl selectableItemsControl &&
            e.NewValue is int newIndex &&
            e.OldValue is int oldIndex)
        {
            if (selectableItemsControl.ContainerFromIndex(oldIndex) is ListViewItem oldListViewItem)
            {
                oldListViewItem.IsSelected = false;
            }

            if (selectableItemsControl.ContainerFromIndex(newIndex) is ListViewItem newListViewItem)
            {
                newListViewItem.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <local:CustomItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedIndex="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                <ScrollViewer
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
                    <local:CustomItemsControl
                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}"
                    SelectedIndex="3">
                        <local:CustomItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </local:CustomItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <local:CustomItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:CustomItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </local:CustomItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </local:CustomItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This `CustomItemsControl` let you bind to its `SelectedIndex` but it won't change its selection by clicks.

The caveat is that `ItemsControl` doesn't have scrolling built-in. You need to wrap it with `ScrolViewer` but shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Andrew-however like mm8's answer this also disables scrolling...

Comment: I actually created an example app with 100 items  to check it works. You mean the vertical scrolling for the ListView right?

Comment: Thanks Andrew-your example does do what my original question asked but I had oversimplified the scenario whilst trying to reduce it for SO. I've expanded the question.

Comment: Since you have 2 ListViews nested, you have to show which MyItem is selected and also you have to show which SubItem is selected in each MyItem, but you don't want any selection changed by clicks. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I update my answer with custom control. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example handle the `ContainerContentChanging` event and set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the containers to `false`:

```
private void OnContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = args.ItemContainer as ListViewItem;
    lvi.IsHitTestVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mm8-unfortunately this also disables scrolling...

Comment: Scrolling of the `ListView`? No, it doesn't. I tested it. You can scroll the `ListView`.

Comment: You are correct. I'd oversimplified the question (now clarified) and had attempted to scroll the sub-lists.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question then since the original one was already answered?

Comment: Your answer provides a workaround (disabling cursor interaction on list items) to the problem posed by the original question (how can you prevent the user selecting items by clicking). The workaround may solve some similar scenarios, but as it is a workaround on balance I think it is better to edit the existing question, in case there is a solution that can disable user selection of items.

Comment: "Workaround on balance"? It's a working solution proposal to your original request of "I would like to stop the user from being able to select other items in the ListView, for example by clicking them". What more can you ask for?

Comment: It does disable user selection of items by the way. It's unclear what you mean by workaround. Is there a difference between a workaround and a solution or what's your point?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/work-around In this case, disabling all interaction when only one bit of interaction was to be disabled